# How to change the fb like button status to liked programatically

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I need to show the users who logged in to the my iOS app,

if they have already liked the page as following

[image: LIKED STATUS]

I have already add the FB Like button and it works perfectly.

```
FBSDKLikeControl *likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] init];
  likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/mypage";
  likeButton.center = self.view.center;
  [self.view addSubview:likeButton];
```

I cannot find a way to mark it as liked. Can you please help me on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer This Page it has All the Stuff Required!!

[LIKE BUTTON FOR IOS APP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/like-button)

Refer Link for more Details

STEPS:
First Add Framework

Then Add Button

**Button Code:**
    //  ViewController.m (example)

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  FBSDKLikeControl *likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] init];
  likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers";
  likeButton.center = self.view.center;
  [self.view addSubview:likeButton];
 }
 @end
```

Comment: i have already add the fb like control. what i need is way to marked it as liked if the user has liked the page previously.

Comment: Is "Facebook Login Implementation" completed?

Comment: Yes its done. Like functionality is also working fine. The only issue if user has liked the page already, how to show it after user logged in.